# Why cant I open a text file when I use the wrong file extension while trying to open it?

Tags: go

I'm trying to read a .txt file using Go, but I keep getting told that the program cannot find the specified file, even when I use the complete path to it. However, the code I have has no problem reading .go files.

Help?

```
package main

import (
"bufio"
"fmt"
"log"
"os"
)


func main() {
// Open an input file, exit on error.
    inputFile, err := os.Open("main.go");
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error opening input file:", err)
    }
    defer inputFile.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(inputFile)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(scanner.Err())
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're not in the folder you think you are.  Provide a full path for the `Open()` method.

Comment: your "open" code is just fine. probably something like a space in the path, capital letters, a typo, etc.

Comment: @RobertHarvey OP says he put the complete absolute path and it still doesn't work. probably a problem with the file name or something.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: I don't see an absolute path in his sample code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `"the program cannot find the specified file, even when I use the complete path to it."`

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: `os.Open("main.go");`

Comment: yeah, he claims this works but the other file isn't. anyway, the code if fine,  I'm voting to close.

Comment: This is a version that works. When I change "main.go" to "test.txt", which exists in the same directory as main.go, it stops working.

Comment: I can't replicate this whatsoever, using both `go run main.go` and `go build main.go && ./main` - opening at text file in the same dir. What operating system are you using, what version of Go and how/where are you running your Go program?

Comment: The question and title do not match what the author is asking. The real question should be "Why cant I read a text file when I try to open it with the wrong file name".

Answer (score 1):

You can see where you are adding this snippet of code at the beginning of your main function:

http://play.golang.org/p/DqnivLi1Z2

```
cwd, err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("os.Getwd ", err)
}
log.Println("Current Directory", cwd)
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(cwd)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ioutil.ReadDir", err)
}

for idx, finfo := range files {
    log.Println(idx, " ", finfo.Name)
}
```

Comment: This outputs 0X401840 for all files in that directory, I'm guessing that's not normal

Comment: @WilliamSmith: I suspect line 24 `log.Println(idx, " ", finfo.Name)` should have been `log.Println(idx, " ", finfo.Name())`. It's printing the `Name` function address not the `Name()` function result, the file name.

Comment: @peterSO That was right...and revealed my problem. The file had an extra ".txt" appended to it. I'm not sure how I missed that